# How to merge two classifiers in appropriate way if they are used on incosistent data

Tags: statistics, machine-learning

My data set consist of two disjoint subsets. There are two different classifiers with confidence measure, each can work only on one definite subset. I need to enhance accuracy of my system on the whole data, so I need to "combine" confidences of these classifiers. The point is that scales of classifiers can be sharply different, e.g. at one confidence level error and accept can be much different. Maybe there is a way to transform confidences to some uniform scale for both classifiers?
Accuracy means maximization of accept level subject to fixed error rate (for example, 10% of data set)

Comment: hm, stackoverflow is more for showing off some code, I belive your question is better targeted at math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Najzero even better would be stats.stackexchange.com , but I'd say it is correct question even here (it is correctly tagged with machine-learning)

Answer (score 0):

what about to make 3rd classifier which would make use of your 2 classifiers(input) and its output should be what you expect

Comment: Thanks, but I wrote that I can't use results of both classifiers for some object simultaneously.

Comment: hmm i was through the question several times but i didn't find it. if you are not working with some time series I can't imagine the situation - maybe some example would help ...

Answer (score 0):

How about combining classifiers through boosting. The paper titled "Boosting Localized Classifiers in Heterogeneous Databases" paper gives more detail.